# how to use selected arduino libraries?

Tags: arduino, avr, atmelstudio

I would like to know if it is possible to use selective arduino libraries in our AVR projects. For Example: I am using Atmega328 and Atmel studio. I would like to use DS1307 related library file(twi.c and Wire.c source files I guess) in my project. Can we use individual libraries and then include applicable header files in our build? If so where are these libraries located and what is the extension? I saw few articles on building entire arduino project in Atmel studio and I am not interested in that. I want to manage without installing arduino if possible (I can install arduino only to get library if needed). I thought of including source files, but they are in C++ and I started getting error messages when included in C project. Is it possible to do without modifying the source files much?

Comment: I'd go with including the source files (if I remember well they are in the arduino installation folder). However these libraries are built for the arduino environment, so you'd have to search for any specific function (`digitalRead`\`Write`, `millis()`, ...) and re-write them...

Answer (score 0):

After searching, i found that

> Any 5V microcontroller with I2C built-in can easily use the DS1307.

check also first lines [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/ds1307-real-time-clock-breakout-board-kit/arduino-library).

I look quickly at `DS1307.c` and found it is not using any functions from `wire.c`

But instead of all that you could get source code for `DS1307.c` and implement any function begin with `i2c` by yourself and small modifications for interrupt functions. and you can use it in your code. i downloaded the library from this [link](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwi9mKjnseXHAhUDtRQKHXAkCHQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpicmania.garcia-cuervo.net%2Frecursos%2F_ds1307.c&usg=AFQjCNFL5ecslTg101bgq5dIW6LYQyFogA&bvm=bv.102022582,d.d24).

There are a lot of twi/i2c libraries for avr, you could download most suitable one and rename it's function like the function called from `DS1307.c`

Comment: Thanks for the update. My fault in the original post. 1307 was only an example I gave and edited it now. Basically I  am asking question in general and want to know if we can borrow selective libraries from arduino and integrate with our code with no or minor changes. If I integrate full arduino, my footprint will go up.